# FB.login bookmarking and iframe. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {

    } else {
    }
}, {scope:'user_birthday,email,publish_actions'});
```

This creates a popup, is it possible to make it appear in an iframe?

I am calling this on an external website version of a Facebook iframe canvas app. Once the app is authorized (on an external website), it is not added to the app bookmarks on Facebook. How can I force it to add the app to app bookmarks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Re: Iframing the login**

It's not possible to iframe the login popup page because, like most pages on facebook.com, it includes an [X-Frame-Options: deny](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) header and meta tag to prevent this (as a way to mitigate against [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)).

**Re: adding a bookmark**

In the past there was a way to add them manually, but [now its fully automatic](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/396), based on how recently apps were used. Also, bookmarks aren't shown for external sites, a canvas app is needed. So the only way to ensure a bookmark is in place is to have a canvas app and to keep users engaged with it.